# variable already been declared after loading modal via htmx (after first load)

Tags: javascript, django, formset, htmx

I'm loading a form using django in a modal (using htmx). I'm using a little vanilla javascript to load formsets dynamically as seen in this tutorial [Dynamically Add Forms in Django with Formsets and JavaScript](https://www.brennantymrak.com/articles/django-dynamic-formsets-javascript). Everything is working fine when you first load the modal but return an error when you load the modal a second time. After form saving I forced a complete reload of the page (not ideal as I want to refresh only a partial) but the problem is there when you load the modal. From what I understand (very little about JS) the problem is you cannot declare a variable more than 1 time using let (you can do let let ingredientForm = ... and only ingredientForm the second time) but obviously is not possible in my case as the script is loaded every time I fire the modal. Any solution?

views.py

```
@login_required
def recipe_create(request):
    user = request.user
    template = "recipes/partials/_recipe_create.html"

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
        formset = IngredientFormSet(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            recipe = form.save(commit=False)
            recipe.creator = user
            recipe.save()
            for form in formset:
                if form.cleaned_data:
                    name = form.cleaned_data["name"]
                    ingredient, created = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=name)
                    RecipeIngredient.objects.get_or_create(
                        ingredient=ingredient,
                        recipe=recipe,
                    )
            return HttpResponse(status=204, headers={"HX-Redirect": reverse_lazy("recipes:recipe_list")})
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
        context = {"recipe_form": form, "ingredient_formset": formset}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

template.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load extra_filters thumbnail %}

{% block page_title %}Ricette{% endblock page_title %}


{% block content %}
<div id="modal" class="modal fade show">
  <div id="dialog" class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-fullscreen-md-down" hx-target="this">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main" class="container my-5 px-3 px-sm-0">
  <div class="d-md-flex align-items-center text-center justify-content-between">
    <div class="d-md-flex align-items-center">
      <h1 class="me-4">Ricette</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm d-none d-md-inline {% if user.is_anonymous %}disabled{% endif %}"
          hx-get="{% url 'recipes:recipe_create' %}"
          hx-target="#dialog"
          hx-trigger="click">
          Aggiungi Ricetta
      </button>
    </div>
    <form class="d-md-flex d-none" role="search">
      <input name="recipe-search" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Cerca Ricetta" aria-label="Search"
          hx-post="{% url 'recipes:recipe_search' %}" hx-trigger="keyup changed delay:500ms" hx-target="#recipe-list" hx-swap="outerHTML">
    </form>
  </div>
{% block recipe_create %}
  <div id="recipe-create" class="mb-4">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm d-block d-md-none {% if user.is_anonymous %}disabled{% endif %}"
        hx-get="{% url 'recipes:recipe_create' %}"
        hx-target="#dialog"
        hx-trigger="click">Aggiungi Ricetta</a>
      <form class="d-flex d-md-none mt-3" role="search">
        <input name="recipe-search" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Cerca Ricetta" aria-label="Search"
          hx-post="{% url 'recipes:recipe_search' %}" hx-trigger="keyup changed delay:500ms" hx-target="#recipe-list" hx-swap="outerHTML">
      </form>
  </div>
{% endblock recipe_create %}
  <hr>

  
  {% block recipes_list %}
  {% if page_obj %}
  <section id="recipe-list" hx-trigger="recipeSaved from:body"
    hx-get="{% url 'recipes:recipe_list' %}">
    <!--  RECIPES LIST  -->
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Ricetta</th>
          <th scope="col">Ingredienti</th>
          <th scope="col">Categoria</th>
          <th scope="col">Tag</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          {% for recipe in page_obj %}
          <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">
              <a href="{% url 'recipes:recipe_detail' recipe.id recipe.slug %}">{{ recipe.title|title}}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle">{% include 'includes/ingredient_list_comma.html' %}</td>
            <td>
              <img src="{{ recipe.category.image|thumbnail_url:'thumbnail' }}" alt="{{ recipe.category.name }}" class="tag-icon">
              <a href="#">{{ recipe.category.name }}</a>
            </td>
              <td class="align-middle">
                {% for tag in recipe.tags.all %}
                  <img src="{{ tag.icon.url }}" alt="{{ tag.label }}" class="tag-icon">
                {% endfor %}
              </td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--  END RECIPES LIST  -->
    <!-- PAGINATION -->
    <nav aria-label="Recipes navigation" class="d-flex justify-content-md-end justify-content-center my-4">
    {% if page_obj.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
      <ul class="pagination pagination-sm me-5">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a href="?page=1" aria-label="First" class="page-link">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous" class="page-link">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for page_number in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}

        {% if page_number == page_obj.number %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link active" href="?page={{ page_number }}">{{ page_number }}</a></li>
        {% else %}
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_number }}">{{ page_number }}</a></li>
        {% endif %}


        {% endfor %}
        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}" aria-label="Last">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
      {% endif %}
      {% if number_of_recipes >= 10 %}
        <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
          <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?items=5" hx-boost="true" hx-target="#recipe-list" class="page-link {% if selected_number_of_items == '5' %}active{% endif %}">5</a>

          </li>
          <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?items=10" hx-boost="true" hx-target="#recipe-list" class="page-link {% if selected_number_of_items == '10' %}active{% endif %}">10</a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?items=25" hx-boost="true" hx-target="#recipe-list" class="page-link {% if selected_number_of_items == '25' %}active{% endif %}">25</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    </nav>
    <!-- END PAGINATION -->
  </section>
  {% else %}
  <p class="text-center fst-italic my-5">Nessuna ricetta presente del database</p>
  {% endif %}

  
  {% endblock recipes_list %}

</div>


{% endblock content %}
```

partial_template.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div id="dialog" class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-fullscreen-md-down" hx-target="this">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5">Crea la tua ricetta</h1>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="form-container" hx-post="{% url 'recipes:recipe_create' %}" hx-target="this">
                {% crispy recipe_form %}
                    <hr class="text-black-50">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-baseline mb-3 ">
                        <h5 class="flex-grow-1">Ingredienti</h5>
                        <button id="add-form" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success me-2">
                            <i class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill me-2"></i>Ingrediente
                        </button>
                        <button id="delete-form" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                            <i class="bi bi-dash-circle-fill me-2"></i>Ingrediente
                        </button>
                    </div>
                        <div id="ingredient-form-list">
                            {{ ingredient_formset.management_form }}
                            {% for formset in ingredient_formset %}
                                <div class="ingredient-form">
                                    {% crispy formset %}
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                <div class="text-end">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Salva</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancella</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    let ingredientForm = document.querySelectorAll(".ingredient-form")
    let ingredientFormList = document.querySelector('#ingredient-form-list')
    let container = document.querySelector("#form-container")
    let addButton = document.querySelector("#add-form")
    let deleteButton = document.querySelector("#delete-form")
    let totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")
    let formNum = ingredientForm.length-1 // Get the number of the last form on the page with zero-based indexing

    checkDisableState(deleteButton) //Disable deleteButton when only initial formset is present
    addButton.addEventListener('click', addForm)

    function addForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
    
        let newForm = ingredientForm[0].cloneNode(true) //Clone the ingredient form
        let formRegex = RegExp(`form-(\\d){1}-`,'g') //Regex to find all instances of the form number
    
        formNum++ //Increment the form number
        newForm.innerHTML = newForm.innerHTML.replace(formRegex, `form-${formNum}-`) //Update the new form to have the correct form number
        ingredientFormList.append(newForm) //Insert the new form at the end of the list of forms
    
        totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum+1}`) //Increment the number of total forms in the management form
        checkDisableState(deleteButton) //Disable deleteButton when only initial formset is present
    }


    deleteButton.addEventListener('click', deleteForm)

    function deleteForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        let lastForm = ingredientFormList.lastChild //Get the last form of the list
        lastForm.remove()
        
        formNum--
        totalForms.setAttribute('value', `${formNum+1}`) //Decrement the number of total forms in the management form
        checkDisableState(deleteButton) //Disable deleteButton when only initial formset is present
    }

    function checkDisableState(e) {
        if (formNum == 0)
            e.setAttribute('disabled', '')
        else
            e.disabled = false
    }
 </script>
```

custom.js(for populating the modal using htmx)

```
const modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("modal"))

htmx.on("htmx:afterSwap", (e) => {
    // Response targeting #dialog => show the modal
    if (e.detail.target.id == "dialog") {
        modal.show()
    }
})

htmx.on("htmx:beforeSwap", (e) => {
    // Empty response targeting #dialog => hide the modal
    if (e.detail.target.id == "dialog" && !e.detail.xhr.response) {
        modal.hide()
        e.detail.shouldSwap = false
    }
})

htmx.on("hidden.bs.modal", () => {
    document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = ""
})
```

error when getting the modal fired up a second time (so the dynamic form adding is not working anymore)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'ingredientForm' has already been declared
    at ot (htmx.min.js:1:19317)
    at at (htmx.min.js:1:19410)
    at htmx.min.js:1:8026
    at htmx.min.js:1:34917
    at W (htmx.min.js:1:3851)
    at a (htmx.min.js:1:34893)
```

I want to be able to use the script every time I open the modal, not only on the first time. Is there any way to reset variables when closing the modal?

Answer (score 3):

Solved my problem declaring variables using var and not let as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var) so the script has been changed to this:

```
<script>
        var ingredientForm = document.querySelectorAll(".ingredient-form")
        var ingredientFormList = document.querySelector('#ingredient-form-list')
        var container = document.querySelector("#form-container")
        var addButton = document.querySelector("#add-form")
        var deleteButton = document.querySelector("#delete-form")
        var totalForms = document.querySelector("#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS")
        var formNum = ingredientForm.length-1 // Get the number of the last form on the page with zero-based indexing

    ...

</script>
```

and now everything is working as expected every time I open the modal